# Adding image in table spanned table row to stay centered relative to other non-spanned rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

Trying to use the below for an email signature, but I cannot get the image in the spanned row to remain centered in all email clients - it works in JSBin fine, but it shows uneven when loaded in GMail. What do I need to change to get it showing correctly (centered) in GMail?

https://jsbin.com/yojinow/1/edit?html,output

[image: uneven display in GMail]

[image: the yellow highlighted section is where the table becomes uneven in GMail]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; vertical-align: baseline;" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by uneven? Could you please give a screenshot of it when it is uncentered?

Comment: @Saeed I have updated the question to show where - please see the yellow highlighted rectangle

Comment: @Matthew Malone, Check my answer..
if not works , send me your result.

Comment: Im sorry, but even with your marks i dont know what you are asking for.

Comment: @Matthew Malone, my answer works for you..try it.

Answer (score 0):

The image must have `display: block` property to be able to have the 100% height 
Try to replace `display: inline-block;` from the image to `display: block;` 
And look at this example

```css
#TemplateLogo{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#TemplateLogo2{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

tbody{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

h3{
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<h3>With display: block;</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<h3>With display: inline-block;</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo2" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change image `height` value to `auto`.

```
<img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; vertical-align: baseline;" height="auto" width="100%">
```

this may works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Made it better, but image is still not centred vertically

Comment: @Matthew Malone, update image styles . I have updated my answer...Try it

Comment: @MatthewMalone, since CSS media queries are not fully support for email templates, this kind of issues raised.So you need to adjust font & image sizes as they are match mobile devices as well...Have a look at this.I have made small adjustments.  http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/20p8eobx/2/

Comment: @MatthewMalone, check this fiddle.Now it should be worked. 
 http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/20p8eobx/30/

Answer (score 0):

Please use css:

```
 height: auto; // On the <td rowspan="4"...>
```

and on the image:

```
 display: block;
 height: 70px;
```

.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: auto; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
                <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" style="display: block; height: 70px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; vertical-align: baseline;" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                    John Doe
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                    Accounts
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
                    T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
                    E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still has the same problem when viewed on Gmail

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying 4 columns with 18px each, but the column where the image dwells you're specifying 70px. It should be 72px (18px x 4 = 72px) (column and image). You may need to change the text to baseline if you want to align them on the baseline.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4" style="width: 72px; height: 72px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
                  <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; vertical-align: baseline;" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                  <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                    John Doe
                  </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                  Accounts
                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
                  T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                  F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
                <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
                  E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite CSS properties for aligning things is `transform` because it is quick and easy. If you are looking for this to be viewable on mobile devices, I suggest you not use `px` but `em` or something like that.

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img {
  transform: translateY(0.15em);
}
```

```html
<h3>With display: block;</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<h3>With display: inline-block;</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo2" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img {
  transform: translateY(0.15em);
}
<h3>With display: block;</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h3>With display: inline-block;</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 390px; height: 70px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; padding-right: 0px; overflow: auto;" vertical-align:"middle" valign="middle">
              <a href="http://google.com.au"><img id="TemplateLogo2" data-class="external" src="https://dummyimage.com/70.png" alt="Company Name" height="100%" width="100%"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
              <font style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
                John Doe
              </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(81, 81, 81);">
              Accounts
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              T:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
              F:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+6199999999" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">(02) 4399 9999</a>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px; width: 264px; height: 18px;">
            <font style="color: #515151; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
              E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:example@example.com.au" style="color: #7cc0cb; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0px solid #7cc0cb;">example@example.com.au</a>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```